# Sorting core data managed objects based on category method

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a simple person class with some simple properties that are persisted using Core Data. Based on certain selections that the user makes I also need to calculate a value based on those selections (like dates), and other information. Since the selections of dates and other information is actually based on the user's selection in that given moment, I do not want to persist this information, so I am storing this information elsewhere.

What is the best way to:

1. calculate some information based on those selections? I have concluded so far that the best approach is to use a category method.
2. Sort an array of persons using this calculated field? As far as I can tell the fetching does not support using a category method to sort on.

Appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: Why use a category method? Can't you just add a property or method to your NSManagedObject subclass? You can sort the array just like you'd sort any other array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a transient field in core data and return the calculation result from them.

> You specify the type of the transient attribute as undefined
>   (NSUndefinedAttributeType). Since Core Data does not need to store and
>   retrieve transient properties, you can use any object type you want
>   for the attribute in your implementation
>   source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdNSAttributes.html

Comment: I tried using the transient attribute option, but wasn't quite successful. Do you happen to know of a good sample, that shows how the header and implementation file would be?

Comment: http://davemeehan.com/technology/objective-c/core-data-transient-properties-on-nsmanagedobject

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that. But I am confused about the following statement:
"The above code is as generated from the Core Data modeller in Xcode. The only thing to note here is that the fullName property includes the transient option, and as a result the underlying SQLite table will not contain a fullName column."  In the code sample he shows the fullName property is exactly like all the others. How do you specify a transient property?

Comment: Open core data xcdatamodeld, select the attribute you want to become transient and open the utilities pane in the right side.

Comment: Thank you, that was the little piece I was missing :-) Appreciate your help!